# How to keep jittering plot points onto border of facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to jitter some points that I have plotted within a `facet_grid` (columns are gene names), but the points keep jittering such that they overlap the border of the facet grid. Is there an easy way to avoid this?

Code below:

```
ggplot(Figure, aes(x = 0, y = Number, col = Status)) + 
  geom_point(size = 9, alpha = 0.6, position = position_jitter(w = 0.1)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Gene, scales =  NULL) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 22), 
        axis.title.y=element_text(size = 20, face="bold"), 
        axis.text.y =element_text(size=18, face="bold",)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Red" = "firebrick3", 
                                "Gold" = "gold", 
                                "Green" = "forestgreen")) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 18, face="bold.italic")) + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=14, face = "bold")) +  
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Points jittered onto facet borders:

[image: Points jittered onto border of facet_grid]

Comment: Please provide the `Figure` dataframe (edit your post and paste the output of `dput(Figure)`).

Comment: Reduce the amount of jitter (`position_jitter`) or expand your x-axis (`scale_x_continuous(expand = `.